# Diary Web Application

Tags: web-applications, uml

I'm developing a Diary application, currently at the beginning stage.

With regards to OO, the Diary is an Object.  Underneath the Diary would contain a Notebook and a Scheduler.

- Notebook: Contains a few paragraphs on today (life story etc)
- Scheduler: Contains ToDo, e.g. visit Dr at 9:30am.

The question is would they both be Object separated from Diary in a UML?  Or would they be part of the Diary?

I imagine they'd be separate objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UML is just a visual representation of your application. This means that the Notebook and the Scheduler would be whatever you intend them to be in your code.

Also, UML has 14 or so types of diagrams and every one of them represents your application (or part of it) from a different point of view. You should [check them out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language#Diagrams_overview).

Comment: I think the classes in the diagram (using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) should be Notebook and Scheduler.

Comment: Yes, that way it would be easy and you won't have any problems with old functionality if you decide to add new functionality (e.g. class Calendar or whatever).